# Users logging through ipad and mobile in salesforce

Tags: user-management, login

How do i find out whether the user is using ipad or mobile to logging into salesforce ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't get that. Because if the user uses Safari in iPad or iPhone it will be displayed as **Browser** in login history. You can only differentiate between API login and browser login.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify same using Apex code :

```
     //for checking on which platform page is working
 public String checkPlatform(){
    String retVal = '';
    String userAgent = ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('USER-AGENT');
    //& some devices use custom headers for the user-agent.
    if( String.isBlank( userAgent ) )
        userAgent = ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('HTTP_X_OPERAMINI_PHONE_UA');
    //& some devices use custom headers for the user-agent.
    if( String.isBlank( userAgent ) )
        userAgent = ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('HTTP_X_SKYFIRE_PHONE');

    //& replace with custom setting - using (?i) case insensitive mode.
    String deviceReg = '(?i)(iphone|ipod|ipad|blackberry|mobile|android|palm|windows\\s+ce)';//iphone|ipod|ipad|blackberry|mobile|android|palm|windows\\s+ce
    String ipadReg = '(?i)(ipad)';
    String iphoneReg = '(?i)(iphone)';
    String mobileReg = '(?i)(mobile)';
    String androidReg = '(?i)(android)';
    String desktopReg = '(?i)(windows|linux|os\\s+[x9]|solaris|bsd)';
    String botReg = '(?i)(spider|crawl|slurp|bot)';
    Matcher ipadM = Pattern.compile( ipadReg ).matcher( userAgent );
    Matcher iphoneM = Pattern.compile( iphoneReg ).matcher( userAgent );
    Matcher mobileM = Pattern.compile( mobileReg ).matcher( userAgent );
    Matcher androidM = Pattern.compile( androidReg ).matcher( userAgent );

    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(deviceReg).matcher(userAgent);
    if( m.find(0) )
    {
        if( ipadM.find(0) || ( !mobileM.find(0) && androidM.find(0) ) )
        {
            retVal = 'Tablet';
            system.debug('This is for tablet');
        }
        else if( iphoneM.find(0) || ( mobileM.find(0) && androidM.find(0) ) )
        {
            retVal = 'Phone';
            system.debug('This is for Phone');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        m = Pattern.compile(desktopReg).matcher(userAgent);
        if( m.find(0) )
            retVal = 'desktop';
        m = Pattern.compile(botReg).matcher(userAgent);
        if( m.find(0) )
            retVal = 'desktop';
            system.debug('This is for desktop');
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

and in init method redirect user to page you want by checking :

```
        if(checkPlatform() == 'desktop'){
         pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/pageName');
         return pageRef;
    }
```

Hope this will help you !!!